# Write JSON to text file from JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a bunch of JSON objects stored in an array in JQuery. Is there an easy way to rewrite them to a JSON text file to my local machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Open gedit or other text editor.  Copy from console. Paste in file. Save as array.json.

**EDIT**
Chrome supports `copy` so you could do `copy("foobar")` and "foobar" will be on your clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Data URI Scheme to convert the JSON to an "URL" which can be then downloaded, i.e.

```
/* Firstly you'll need a javascript library which can encode data to base 64
 * http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/base64  - jQuery Plugin
 * http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html - Collection of functions
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/6740027/451672         -     ''     ''     "
 */

/* Now we must convert the JSON to text, which can be done with the 
   JSON.stringify() method
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.85).aspx
 */

var data = JSON.stringify(myObject);

/* Now we convert the data to a Data URI Scheme, which must be Base64 encoded
   make sure you use the appropriate method to Base64 encode your data depending
   on the library you chose to use.
 * application/octet-stream simply tells your browser to treat the URL as 
   arbitrary binary data, and won't try to display it in the browser window when 
   opened.
 */
var url = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + Base64.encode(data);

/* To force the browser to download a file we need to use a custom method which
   creates a hidden iframe, which allows browsers to download any given file 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/3749395/451672
 */
var downloadURL = function(url)
{
    var iframe;
    iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
    if (iframe === null)
    {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
        iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;   
}

/* Now downloading is simple as executing the following code, make sure that
   the DOM is not modified until after the page has finished loading!
 */
window.onload = function()
{
    var link = document.getElementById("downloadJSON");
    link.onclick = function()
    {
        downloadURL(url);
    }
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cQV7X/

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) that allows you to read and write to a local file.